# Add columns in dataframe together if colnames are in list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add together power plant hourly output data at different locations.

I have a series of the generators at each location

```
genLocations = pd.Series

MDN         SL1
HEN         WF34, SL2
OTA         WF26, SL3
HLY         WF16, WF27, SL4
```

i.e. locations are on the left and generators on the right.

I then need to add together the columns of another dataframe which contains the hourly output of different generators. I need to sum each column of generators to a single location.

```
gen = pd.Dataframe

                WF1  WF2  WF3  WF4  WF5  ...  SL15  SL16  SL17  SL18  SL19
2007_1_1_p1     9.0  0.0  6.0  8.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2007_1_1_p2     8.0  0.0  7.0  8.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2007_1_1_p3     0.0  8.0  7.0  8.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2007_1_1_p4     4.0  0.0  6.0  8.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2007_1_1_p5     0.0  0.0  7.0  8.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

My final output should look something like this

```
nodes = pd.Dataframe

             MDN    HEN   OTA   HLY   ....
2007_1_1_p1  7.0   5.0   4.0    6.0   ....
2007_1_1_p2  0.0   0.0   7.0    8.0   ....
```

So far I have tried

```
for index, i in genLocations.iteritems():
    nodes[index] = gen[[i]].sum(axis='columns')
```

Comment: Is `genLocations` a series of lists or of strings?

Comment: @QuangHoang its a series of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try splitting `genLocations` and `explode`:

```
s = genLocations.str.split(', ').explode()

d = {v:k for k,v in s.iteritems()}

nodes.groupby(nodes.columns.map(d), axis=1).sum()
```

**Note**: `explode` is available in Pandas 0.25+.